# Problem launching nam

Tags: ns2

i have a problem launching nam. I get a permissions error and it never
displays the network animation window. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Comment: The command you typed and which resulted in the "permission denied" error does not make any sense. Where did you get the idea to enter that?

Comment: The screenshot is not much help. You cut off the right portion of the commands you typed in. Please edit your question and provide the text of the commands you entered.

Comment: Image: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text → I guess you know how to copy-paste a text...... `sudo apt remove nam` : The Ubuntu nam package is corrupt. Valid packages https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2 → nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb → `sudo apt install ./nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb`